# Angularjs adding row at curent row location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code that is suppose to add another row at current row location (not at the bottom of the rows):

```
<tr ng-repeat="ro in rows">
  <td>{{ro.name}}</td>
  <td>{{ro.id}}</td>
  <td><a ng-click="addRo($index)">add row</a></td>
</tr>
```

In my controller, I have:

```
$scope.addRo=function(index){
     $scope.inderted={
       id: '',
       name: ''
      };
      $scope.rows($index+1).push($scope.inserted);
}
```

I tried the above code hopeing adding index to the current location it would add it, but it doesn't work. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.splice()` instead of `.push()`

```
$scope.addRo=function(index){
  var inderted={
    id: '',
    name: ''
  };
  $scope.rows.splice(index + 1, 0, inderted);
}
```

Here's the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for `.splice()`

Also, there is no need to add 'inderted' to scope if you are just using it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

To insert new element in the array you need to use [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method. In your case:

```
$scope.rows.splice($index+1, 0, $scope.inserted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to the `$index` of the current element within the ng-repeat, inserting a new row is easy.  The problem with your current code is that [`array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) always adds the element to the *end* of the array.

Use [`array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to actually insert elements into the array.

```
$scope.addRo = function(index) {
        var newObj = {
            id: '',
            name: ''
        };
        $scope.rows.splice(index + 1, 0, newObj); //inserts a row after this one
                                                  //use index for a new row here
    };
```